# Bash - How to detect if a variable is more than a certain amount of characters

Tags: bash

```bsh
#/bin/bash
echo "This message may not be more than 8 characters"
read detect
```

How do I detect the number of letters?
Would it be an IF statement?

```bsh
if #detect var
then
else
fi
```

EDIT: How can I make it repeat until the user types a correct message?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix How do I put this code in a loop?

Comment: You mean ```\``` (Forward Slash)? I don't think that applies to the shebang, scripts with #!bin/bash are usally functional. EDIT: Oh I am sorry I didn't understand, I though you were talking about #```\!```/bin/bash, and not that I was missing the first slash.

Comment: @Kulfy What do I do with the ```fi``` at the end?

Comment: I get an error when I use fi at the end :( ```./passkey.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./passkey.sh: line 4: `while [[ ${#detect} -gt 8 ]] ; then'
```

Comment: I have removed my comments and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **if-then-else-fi** like this:

```
if [[ ${#detect} -gt 8 ]] ; then
    echo "Error message..."
    exit 1
else
    echo "Good to go..."
    exit 0
fi
```

`exit 1` generally means failure and `exit 0` generally means success. In either case your script ends immediately when `exit` is encountered so use them appropriately.

You can also use implied **if-then** which is fairly unique the the shell language:

```
[[ ${#detect} -gt 8 ]] && { echo "Error message..." ; exit 1 ; }

# successful code here
exit 0
```

If you didn't need an error message the `{ ... }` braces aren't required for a single command eg:

```
[[ ${#detect} -gt 8 ]] && exit 1
```

can be used to say "If the variable named detect is > 8 then exit".

---

### Enhancing the process

Generally it is considered rude to allow the user only one chance to input a string. The polite method is to ask for the string again after telling them it needs to be 8 characters or less. For example:

```
echo "Enter character string 1 to 8 characters long or press <CTRL>+C to exit."
while True ; do
    read StringVar
    [[ ${#StringVar} -ge 1 ]] && [[ ${#StringVar} -le 8 ]] && break
    echo "Sorry that string is ${#StringVar} long. Please try again."
done

# successful code here
```

In this case the program keeps requesting input until variable `StringVar` is obtained and it is **greater than or equal to 1** *AND* it is **less than or equal to 8** at which point the `while` look is broken out of with the `break` command.

Alternately the user can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+C/kbd> to terminate the bash script.

The concise lines:

```
[[ ${#StringVar} -ge 1 ]] && [[ ${#StringVar} -le 8 ]] && break
echo "Sorry that string is ${#StringVar} long. Please try again."
```

... can be made ridiculously verbose like this:

```
if [[ ${#StringVar} -ge 1 ]] ; then
    if [[ ${#StringVar} -le 8 ]] ; then
        break
    else
        echo "Sorry that string is ${#StringVar} long. Please try again."
        continue
    fi
else
    echo "Sorry that string is ${#StringVar} long. Please try again."
    continue
fi
```

Although not incorrect it is wasteful to both the programmer's and system's time.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to ask the user for input again and again until the length of input less than 8 characters. If so, you can use `while` loop instead of `if-else` statements. In that, loop will continue for infinite times until the length of input is less than 8 characters. When the length of "input" is less than 8 characters only then the script continues. The code will something like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter message with less than 8 characters: "
read detect
while [[ ${#detect} -gt 8 ]]
do
        echo -n "Length of the message was greater than 8. Try again...: "
        read detect
done
echo $detect 
#and the rest of the code continues
```

Moreover, if you are running the script from root (`/`) folder, then the shebang `#!bin/bash` might work (which you mentioned in the [original post](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1198184/1)) but if you are running that from elsewhere, include the absolute path of the interpreter, i.e. `/bin/bash`, therefore modifying shebang to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: My apologies I thought of something similar about the same time you posted your answer. I updated my answer after work before seeing what you posted.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Why apologise?  **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: It's wrong to repeat someone's answer. Just wanted you to know I didn't see your answer until after I revised my own.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Oh I see. No problem in that :)